# Multiple WebViews load url performance bad

Tags: android, webview

My MainActivity has three tabs. Each tab is a fragment with a WebView. When tab A is loading web resources(html/js/css/js execution). Tab B's WebView page loading maybe affected by tab A, since all WebViews' page loading is executed on a single thread. It causes tab B WebView page loading dramatic slow since tab A is loading.

How can I fix this performance problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to load webview B when A complete, webview C when B complete with WebView
event, just load the displayed tab first. Or load webview when you click on the tab (if you dont have to preload the webviews), if you want to preload other webview try something like this :

```
yourWebViewInstanceA.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // Load the next Webview here
  }
});
```